# Raspbian boot up splash screen

Tags: raspberry-pi, splash-screen, raspbian, raspberry-pi4

We have a raspberry pi 4 based device with a display, and when it is booting, it should start our program (which is does as init.d service). It boots up to console and then starts the program as it should. While booting, it should show nothing but a splash screen. However, when booting, it shows different text output on the screen, and the splash screen (set at /usr/share/plymouth/themes/pix) only shows up for a few seconds, to make place for even more text output, before our program's display appears. It does not look nice. It should show the splash screen image as soon as it can, and do not show any text output, before the program starts. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Probably a question for [raspberrypi.se].